# jmeter Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException

Tags: jmeter

I am ruining a simple HTTP Request gmail login page.
i am getting below error.can anyone please help to solve this problem.

> Thread Name: mygroup 1-1 Sample Start: 2017-02-22 12:23:25 CAT Load
>   time: 21094 Connect Time: 21093 Latency: 0 Size in bytes: 2206 Headers
>   size in bytes: 0 Body size in bytes: 2206 Sample Count: 1 Error Count:
>   1 Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text Response code: Non HTTP response
>   code: java.net.ConnectException Response message: Non HTTP response
>   message: Connection timed out: connect Response headers:
>   HTTPSampleResult fields:

[image]

Comment: Please, don't ruin the Gmail login page.

Answer (score 2):

If your web application having SSL certificate which is not trusted in this case JMeter/Blazemeter through below error 
Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException 
Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

**Solution:**

Change your HTTP sampler implementation to HttpClient4 
1. Click to advanced Tab of sampler or HTTP Request 
2. Select HttpClient4 option from implementation

[image: HttpClient4]

Comment: Yes this worked for me for the similar issue.thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend practicing load testing using applications you don't own, you can be blacklisted or even worse. Try out the following options instead:

- [Welcome: Mercury Tours](http://newtours.demoaut.com/)
- [BlazeDemo](http://blazedemo.com/)

However for practicing purposes it is better to use a web application deployed in your local intranet so you could measure the load from operating system perspective (CPU, RAM, Disk, Network usage). You can deploy some free and open source CMS like [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) or [Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/) somewhere and use it for your load testing excercises.

---

If you need to check email it is better to do it using JMeter's [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) which can fetch email messages using [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) or [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) protocols. Check out [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for more information and example configuration.

Comment: Although your recommendations are correct, this is not a response to his question. The question clearly asks what does "Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException" mean, and you missed it completely.